# DOM created Delete Button not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, aptana

Ok here is what I was trying to do... Create a delete button along with edit by using DOM while creating a paragraph. But delete button always seems to be deleting first paragraph instead of deleting the corresponding paragraph.. here's my code:

`Javascript:`

```
 function writePara()
 {
    var comment = document.getElementById("usrinput").value;
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = comment;
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var Btext=document.createTextNode("EDIT");
    button.appendChild(Btext);
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(button);

    button.onclick = 
    (
        function() 
        {
    var edit = prompt("Type to edit", "");
    newParagraph.innerHTML = edit;
        }
    );
    var button2 = document.createElement("button");
    var Btext2=document.createTextNode("DELETE");
    button2.appendChild(Btext2);
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(button2);
    button2.onclick = 
    (
        function ()
        {

    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#updateDiv p");
        if (items.length) 
    {
        var child = items[0];
        child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    }
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
    button2.parentNode.removeChild(button2);
        }


    );
    addBr();
  }
```

And the `HTML:`

```
 <body onload="radio()">

    <div id="paraButton" align="left">


        <form><h3>Enter your Paragraph content here:</h3>
<textarea cols="20" rows="10" id="usrinput">Enter your texts here...</textarea>
        </form>


<form id="one"><input type="button" value="Apply" onclick="writePara()"/></form>
        <div id="updateDiv" name ="update"><h1>Space for Paragraph</h1>     </div>

    </div>

    <div id="radioButton">

        <h3>Type your radio button here:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="option" id="option" value="Example 1" />
        </br></br>
        <button id="AddButton">Add</button>
        <button id="RemoveButton">Remove</button>
        </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

        <div id="updateDivRadio"><h1>Space for Radio Button</h1></div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

P.S: the `radio()` function is working fine this is just a segment that I'm having problem with.

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaQQ5/) with the code you provided - would you mind adding some more code to make a working example so we can isolate the problem?

Comment: @kmoe Thanks for the fiddle but its not functioning properly the way my entire code functions. For example when I click `Apply` it creates a new paragraph from the texts in the input area, but in the fiddle nothing happens.

Comment: @kmoe [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nadz006/72ex5/show/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working with the help of others so decided to share here...
Changing `button2.onclick` to this works.

```
 button2.onclick = 
 (
 function ()
 {
    newParagraph.parentNode.removeChild(newParagraph);
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
    button2.parentNode.removeChild(button2);
 }
 );
```